# What does Hinduism say about organ donation?

Tags: practice, dharma, culture

Does the religion say anything good/bad about organ donation ?

Is one not circumventing some sort of karmic rules by giving and receiving organs ? Say, if someone is blind, he is paying for his karma. 
May be getting an eye in donation means his punishment of blindness is over ? But eye transplants are a recent medical advancement. How did the punishment of blindness be over in the past ?

Comment: Saying "that is his karma" when someone is suffering is not the correct definition of Karma. It's a terrible misinterpretation. We must always help what we can do.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma but suffering is a result of karma - isn't it ?

Comment: Everything is Karma but what is the role of other human beings if looking at suffering and say Karma. we are here to help each other.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Don't the scriptures say humans are here to work out their karma ?